# HTML Table - Getting white space between rows on Android devices only

Tags: android, html, css, html-table

I have this HTML Table like so:

```
<table class="table-outline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 750px; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="#" width="750" height="509"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="#" alt="" width="750" height="64"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="#" alt="" width="750" height="83"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="#" alt="" width="750" height="79"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This HTML Table will be an email, but when I goto check this on an android device I get white spaces in between rows...This only happens on an android device, apple is perfect as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

try putting `style="display: block;"` to all the `img`

```html
<table class="table-outline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 750px; border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z6BZDwAE1wGp7FAL+wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="750" height="509" style="display: block;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z/CyHgAGVwJpiy6ZlgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="" width="750" height="64" style="display: block;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk8PxfDwADYgHJvQ16TAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="" width="750" height="83" style="display: block;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="" width="750" height="79" style="display: block;"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```